# GC_CURRENT - Phonegap App crashes

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I want to fill a lottery field with random numbers when the user shakes the phone.

My shake detection

```
function watchForShake(threshold)

{

console.log ("Am Watching for shakes");

axl.watchAcceleration( 
   function (Accel) 

   {

       if (true === Accel.is_updating){

           return; 

       }  

       var diffX = Accel.x - prevX; 

       if (diffX >= threshold)

       {

            console.log("Phone shaken");

            if (gettingRandomNumbers==false){

                randomNumbers();

            }



       }

      prevX = Accel.x

   }

 , function(){} 

 , {frequency : 100}

 );



}
```

this Method sets a number in the lottery field as selected.

```
function clickNumber(number)
{      



console.log("ClickNumber invoked with number "+number);


tNumber   = $(number).html();

tPosition = $(number).position(); 




    if($(number).hasClass('selected'))
    {
        lottoNumbers.pop(number);

        console.log("number.hasClass = true");

        $(number).removeClass('selected'); 

        $(number).children().remove();  



    }else{

        if (lottoNumbers.length <= 5) {

            lottoNumbers.push(number);

            console.log("number.hasClass = false");

            $(number).addClass('selected');

            $(number).append('<img src="assets/images/spielschein_kreuz.png" style="position:absolute;top:'+ tPosition.top +'px;left:'+ tPosition.left +'px;"/>');                                               

        }               

    } 


  }
```

The next method gets random numbers and sets them in the lotteryfield (using jquery). I think this method is what causes the memory leak. The app doesnt crash when I take out the inner for-loop, but I dont know how to fix it.

```
function randomNumbers(){ 

console.log("Am Getting Random Numbers");

gettingRandomNumbers=true;

counter = 0;

clearAllNumbers();



while (counter < 6){ 

        zufallsZahl = Math.floor((Math.random()*49)+1);





        zufallsZahlen[counter]=zufallsZahl;  



        if (isUniqueNumber){

            counter++;

            console.log("Zufallszahl: "+zufallsZahl);

            clickNumber($('#ticket_detail .tipfield .tipbox ul li').filter(function(){return $(this).html() == zufallsZahl;}));

        } 

}

gettingRandomNumbers = false;

}
```

I dont know what exactly causes the GC_CONCURRENT message. The app crashes and freezes without an explicit error message. After several shakes detected, the app crashes.

All variables are initialized in the document.ready() method in the index.html file. I dont create new objects on every shake, do I?

any help or hints greatly appreciated.
thank you, 
Daniel

Comment: Post the output of "adb logcat" as it will probably give us a better idea of why it crashes.

Comment: I dont have a phone here now, cant do it until tomorrow :(. Basically I can say there is no error message except for the GC_CONCURRENT message. But I will print the log tomorrow.